# Does Unix Cache Binaries?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

This is a question for my understanding, I believe that *nix systems rarely required reboot. i.e. if you installed a new "application" or even kernal 9/10 no reboot is required.

I recently installed a random component (liquidsoap dependency) I required from source: camlp4-4.03-1 and noticed the following:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ /usr/local/bin/camlp4 -v
Camlp4 version 4.03.0
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ camlp4 -v
Camlp4 version 4.01.0
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ which camlp4
/usr/local/bin/camlp4
```

I am stumped as to the version mismatch? for what appears to be the same file?
There is no "camlp4" in the present directory :)

```
HW: Raspberry Pi 3
OS: Raspbian Jessie (up to date)
```

---

Information Requested Added:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ find / -name camlp4
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/site-lib/camlp4
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/camlp4
/usr/local/bin/camlp4
/usr/lib/ocaml/camlp4
/usr/share/doc/camlp4
/usr/bin/camlp4
/home/pi/apps/camlp4
/home/pi/apps/camlp4/camlp4-4.03-1/_build/camlp4
/home/pi/apps/camlp4/camlp4-4.03-1/camlp4
/home/pi/apps/ocamlfind/findlib-1.6.2/site-lib-src/camlp4

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ type -a camlp4
camlp4 is /usr/local/bin/camlp4
camlp4 is /usr/bin/camlp4

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ which camlp4
/usr/local/bin/camlp4
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ /usr/bin/camlp4 -v
Camlp4 version 4.01.0
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

---

Testing Solution provided:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ /usr/local/bin/camlp4 -v
Camlp4 version 4.03.0
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ camlp4 -v
Camlp4 version 4.01.0
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ which camlp4
/usr/local/bin/camlp4
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ hash -r
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ camlp4 -v
Camlp4 version 4.03.0
```

Comment: Do a `find / -name camlp4` and check if there's anything else around which may be messing with you.

Comment: Show your `$PATH` and output of `type -a camlp4`.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk and apokryfs... Additional info added.

Comment: I wouldn't describe this as "caching binaries", but merely caching _the path_ to binaries. I think that's a critical distinction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

most shells indeed maintain a cache of the binary to launch for a given command, in order to avoid searching through the `PATH` everytime, and `which` does not know about this cache, which explain the discrepancy you're observing. The way to refresh the cache differs from a shell to another. For `bash` or `dash`, you should do `hash camlp4`. For `zsh`, this is `rehash`.

Comment: The POSIX compliant way to clear the hash is [`hash -r`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/utilities/hash.html). It should work in all more or less POSIX compliant shells, including zsh.